# How to store username and password securely in .NET Core console app?

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core

In my .NET Core console app, I need to store a username and password securely such that when the app is run at a later point in time, I am able to retrieve it without prompting the user again.

The console app will run under Windows.

What is the recommended way to store sensitive information in a Windows program?

Comment: i guess you're logging into some service. from that login, you usually get some kind of token - save that instead.

Comment: Actually, I am :) but nevertheless, the token itself is sensitive. if you have the token, you can do a lot of bad stuff. I would need to store the token securely.

Comment: yeah, but - the token has a limited scope and lifetime. an attacker could do much more damage with the original login credentials than with a token.

Comment: I agree, but only a little bit :P Even though you have a shorter time span to do damage, you can still do it. Anyways, I am required to store it securely. I have no choice in the matter, so the original problem remains.

Comment: What sort of username and password, is it for Windows, for SQL, an API or a custom login procedure

Comment: The short answer is you can't.  You can only make it more difficult, which would deter an amateur hacker, but not a skilled one.  If the app holds the secret, someone can decompile it to discover how it stores and then later retrieves the secret.  What you _could_ do is secure it within that user's context, so a different Windows user could not obtain it.

Comment: @sellotape how do I secure it within the user's context?

Comment: It changes over time, but currently [Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection) is probably the easiest option.

Comment: @Charlieface I don't think it matters. It's something, that if you have access to it, can do harm. It could be nuclear launch codes. The app will be running in Windows.

Comment: It matters very much, because for example authentication to SQL Server from a Windows login doesn't need to store a username and password. Same if it's a service and needs to impersonate another user account. Other credentials can be stored in the user account as mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [ProtectedData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=net-5.0) class. This encrypts the data to make it inaccessible for all but the current user.

Keep in mind that protecting data from the user himself, especially if the user is an administrator, will rarely be truly secure if the user is skilled.